# How to get property of the selenium element?

Tags: java, selenium

I am rewriting python code into java and getting confused to get translate following line:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(),'Hello')]")
id = element.get_property('attributes')[1]['textContent']
```

How should I convert it to Java?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any method `get_property` present for WebElement in Java-Selenium bindings.

You can do following with `getAttribute`

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Hello')]"));
String s = ele.getAttribute("textContent");
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite the [python](/questions/tagged/python) code within the question into [java](/questions/tagged/java) you the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Hello')]"));
String id = element.getAttribute("textContent");
```

As an alternative, instead of `getAttribute("textContent")` you can also use the any of the options below:

- `String id = element.getText();`
- `String id = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");`